# Image Depth Error in NIST FpMV- Beta V3.0 application?

Tags: matlab, fingerprint, feature-extraction

I tried viewing fingerprint minutiae points using Fingerprint Minutiae viewer. When I do it with a grayscale image from database, it works fine. But after performing image processing functions to enhance the image, when I save the output image using "saveas()" command in Matlab and use this image as input to the FpMV application it gives following error:
[Error: Image is not 8-bit grey scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNTjf.png)

I tried converting image to grayscale using "im2unit8" but it gave the same error.
Can someone help me in resolving the error?

Here, I'm attaching snapshot of error along with the GUI interface of FpMV:
[GUI interface of FpMV along with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6640P.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your code. You can use `class` and `size` to check your variables - or your workspace window (alternatively the `whos` command as well).

Comment: Thank you !!! FpMV provides us a GUI interface where we can view minutiae and also see a count of them. I have attached a snapshot of the interface above. Please see it and tell me what should I do. Is there any error in saving the image in Matlab. For that I used the following command: >>h= figure; >>saveas(h,'C:\Users\Mehak\Documents\Image Output\Enhanced 1.png');